# Replacing div content/ value with form input

Tags: javascript, forms, phpbb3

I want to create a form on phpBB3 forum.
Form values would be added to specific div value.

I am aware how to do this with Javascript on button click.
Yet, I do not know, how to force results to stay the same/ be saved to the selected div. I assume messing with database or php would be the case here?

For example:

```
<div id="result">0</div>

<form name="myform">
    <input type="number" name="number1" value="" id="v1" />
</form>

<button id="btnClick">Sum</button>
```

So in this case, after pressing button, #v1 value should be added to #result value.

I do have access to the server and databases, but not sure how this is supposed to work. Can this be done only with Javascript? Any tips appreciated!

Comment: The answer depends on how persistent and secure you need the data to be. If you want high security and persistence, you'll need to send the data to the server and retrieve it when the page loads, which will involve giving each user some sort of unique "key" to identify them. Or, if security and persistence isn't a deal-breaker, you can store the data in `localStorage` and retrieve it upon each page load.

Comment: The security is not an issue at all.

I was thinking maybe, record form input to txt file. And then just SUM the txt file content on page load. Does that make any sense?

Comment: A text file would need to exist on the server and, in that scenario, it would essentially become the database that I talked about.

Comment: I did figure out how to save form values to file on server. Now how would I add up these values and apply result to div? My main concern is, that everything has to be done after pressing same single submit button. The actions would list like this after pressing button: 1) value saved to file; 2) values from file added together SUM; 3) SUM result applied to DIV.

Comment: The math on the file contents would need to be done on the server-side. PHP is a relatively easy server-side technology to implement. After the math is done the result would be sent back to the client and then you can take that and do whatever you want with it in the page.

Comment: Okey... I worked out the SUM. The only part left is how do I assign SUM result to replace div content? I have never worked with PHP, so not sure how this should work... The only way that comes to my mind, is to have result stored and overwritten every time in a separate file. And the file content is called inside the div....